# Is it possible to make LDAP query to trusted domain?

Tags: active-directory

I can make query for the user using the following LDAP query syntax: LDAP://< GUID=guid >. It works fine when I make query over current domain, but fails to work when I query for the user from trusted domain. Is it possible to make such query to trusted domain, when domain trust is established?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to include the DNS name of the domain in the LDAP path, like this:

```
LDAP://domain.com/<GUID={guid}>
```